# matInput value doesn't get updated

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-forms

I have a form Input field for username and password like this,

```
 <mat-form-field class="mdb-form-field-modal form-adjustments">
    <input (keydown)="emailBtnFocus($event)" tabindex="0" matInput placeholder="username" formControlName="username">
        <mat-error *ngIf="username.hasError('email') && !username.hasError('required')">
        {{ signInEmailErrorText }}
        </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="username.hasError('required')">
        {{requiredError }}
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
    signInForm: FormGroup;
  username = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required, Validators.email
  ]);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authState = this.store.select('auth');
    this.signInForm = new FormGroup({
      'username': this.username,
      'password': this.password,
      'staySignedIn': this.staySignedIn
    });

  }
  // Submit Logic.
  onSignInSubmit() {
    console.log('SignInForm:', this.signInForm);
   //logic for submit goes here
  }
}
```

When I click on Submit the value still remains as null and I am not sure why . Can someone help me figure this out ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
signInForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authState = this.store.select('auth');
    this.signInForm = this.formBuilder.group({({
      'username': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      'password': ['', Validators.required],
      'staySignedIn': ['']
    });

  }
  // Submit Logic.
  onSignInSubmit() {
    console.log('SignInForm:', this.signInForm);
   //logic for submit goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ajay. yes I have that in my code and it still doesn't work

Comment: what do you have in your code? did you use 'this.formBuilder.group'?

Comment: if it worked...then please upvote and mark this as the correct answer